# Grouping and returning result only when all records in the group match the criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql

The DB structure is as follow:

Addresses has many Plans
Plans has many Jobs
Jobs has many UserJobs

I'm trying to group all the Jobs done for an specific Address regardless of the Plan.

From there I would only want to see the Addresses that have not had a single successful work done

A successful work is when UserJobs.perfomance = ontime or UserJobs.perfomance = late

```
SELECT
  "addresses"."address1",
  "user_jobs"."performance"

FROM
  "addresses" JOIN "plans" ON "addresses"."id" = "plans"."address_id" 
  JOIN "jobs" ON "plans"."id" = "jobs"."plan_id" 
  JOIN "user_jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "user_jobs"."job_id"

group by   
  "addresses"."address1",
  "user_jobs"."performance"
```

I tried building the query above but I can already see the flaw in it. It will group by address but if there are different performances within that address it will split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* if you want to count successful work done:

```
SELECT
  "addresses"."address1",
  COUNT(CASE 
           WHEN "user_jobs"."performance" IN ('ontime', 'late') THEN 1
        END) AS cnt  
FROM
  "addresses" JOIN "plans" ON "addresses"."id" = "plans"."address_id" 
  JOIN "jobs" ON "plans"."id" = "jobs"."plan_id" 
  JOIN "user_jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "user_jobs"."job_id"    
GROUP BY   
  "addresses"."address1
```

Comment: With a current Postgres version this can also be written as `count(*) filter (where user_jobs.performance in ('ontime', 'late'))`

Answer (score 1):

"all records in the group match the criteria" -> bool_and aggregate function

```
select "addresses"."address1" FROM
    "addresses" JOIN "plans" ON "addresses"."id" = "plans"."address_id" 
    JOIN "jobs" ON "plans"."id" = "jobs"."plan_id" 
    JOIN "user_jobs" ON "jobs"."id" = "user_jobs"."job_id"

   group by   
     "addresses"."address1"
   HAVING bool_and("user_jobs"."performance" IN ('ontime', 'late'))
```